# Android DatePicker, How the

Tags: android, datepicker, calendar

There are two activity:
     In one activity, I used the DatePicker to change the date. 
    This is the code i have used:

```
public class DataTimePicker extends Activity {
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyƒÍMM‘¬dd»’  HH:mm");
        Toast.makeText(DataTimePicker.this,
                format.format(calendar.getTime()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
 }
```

However, when I step into another activity (Main acivity) to show the date, I found the date is not changed, is still at the current date:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    text_date.setText("You choose:"+ c.get(Calendar.YEAR)+c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}
```

Could you tell me how to deal with this issue, I want to show the changed date in the second activity(`MainActivity`).

Comment: you have to use `Intent.putExtra("key", value);` for sending data from an activity to another.

Comment: I am a new one to this, do you have some code about this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like *(note that code is not tested)*:

```
public class DataTimePicker extends Activity {
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year,

          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyyƒÍMM‘¬dd»’  HH:mm");
       Intent i = new Intent(DataTimePicker.this, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("YOUR_DATA", String.valueOf(format.format(calendar.getTime())));
    }

}
```

and in the MainActivity class you do something like:

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras == null) {
    newString= null;
} else {
    newString= extras.getString("YOUR_DATA");
}
```

Comment: Ok! No problem! Just be wait for it! I will go home now, I will vote each answer tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

I can not add comment .. so i will help you here

You have to pass the selected date to your second activity. In your code above you just get the current date every time.

You can use prefferences, intent.putExtra(key,value) or append a variable from your second activity...

Comment: I am a new one to this, do you have some code about this! Thanks! –

Comment: Sure : in your first activity use this to store your date :  SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YOURACTIVITY.this);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
     editor.putString("new_date", var_date); 
    editor.commit();   and in your second activity use : SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YOURSECONDACT.this);
       String var_date= prefs.getString("new_date", null);

Comment: if my comment solution helpd you please click accept my solution to close topic... or vote..

Comment: Of course, I will vote you, let me try it by your code, but thanks in advance!

Comment: Preferences are not a good choice here, they are made for persistence. Intent extras are the only one solution.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that you should know that `Calendar.getInstance()` is not a `Singleton`, it returns a new instance every time you call it.

So to pass an object from an `Activity` to another one, you can check this answer: [Dynamically loading data to a new view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428669/dynamically-loading-data-to-a-new-view/28429169#28429169)

Comment: @KeTian If my explanation helped, you can... just enjoy it. #lol